# Yii2 - Using Another Assets Class Rather Than AppAsset

Tags: yii2

I have an asset's class `AdminAssets`. In this class I have few js, css files for the admin pages. I want the assets mentioned in this class to be included in a view `admin` (action: `actionAdmin`), but I don't want any of the assets listed in `AppAssets` to be included in this view. It's like detaching `AppAssets` and attaching `AdminAssets` only for one view. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To disable publishing `AppAssets` for specific view, include this code before render:

```
use Yii;

...

// Replace 'app\assets\AppAssets' with the actual namespace of your AppAssets

Yii::$app->assetManager->bundles['app\assets\AppAssets'] = false;
```

**Official docs:**

- [Customizing Asset Bundles](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-assets.html#customizing-asset-bundles)

Comment: I placed it at the top of `admin` view file but it seems like they are still being included. I want to remove AppAssets, so I believe I don't have to change this. am I right?

Comment: And I did read that document, but couldn't find that line of code that you have written.

Comment: There is an example here with `JqueryAsset`, but it shows how do it in config. Because you only need to do it for certain view, you need to do it through Asset Manager.

Comment: Tested it right now, it works, I added this code in according controller before rendering view.